# VS Code 1.15.1 The Run Code Toolbar Not Appear in Green Color as It Used to

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need a help. I read VSC Debugging doc and about launch.json. Nothing has helped me so far when searching for an answer on this specific issue in STO and VS Code documentation.

I've been annoyed, frustrated by this little bug in my Visual Studio Code 1.15.1. I worked on python project and things were good and with the run code triangle toolbar on the top right appeared in green color. Then I worked on C project. But when I wanted to go back working on a python project, the run code toolbar did not appear in green color like it used to. I've never changed anything in the setting.
[the run code toolbar/button appeared in green color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjNtY.png)
[the run code toolbar/button not appeared in green color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjZQF.jpg)

Do I need to install AutoLaunch 2.0.3 (Automatically run tasks in tasks.json or launch config in launch.json ) in order to get the green color back on the Run Code button/toolbar?

I just want simply the green color back. What should I do to get that green color back on the run code triangle toolbar? What setting I should change? I was thinking uninstalling my VS Code and reinstalling it should solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall Python extension in vs code and reinstall it ?

Comment: why do you ask the exact same question 1 or two days later, you still have not created the correct location for `launch.json`

Comment: Thank you, guys... I have tried both reinstalling VS Code & Python and been reading this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging too but the issue remains unsolved for me. I'm sorry I'm having difficulty where I should go for changing the setting when reading that documentation, I'm a new user of VS Code:-( Nobody is willing to specifically point out for me which setting I should change in order to get the green color of run code button back normally as it used to be.